# Limit point of isolated singularities in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I came across the following conjecture (?) regarding (non-isolated) singularity in complex analysis: Suppose we have a function of a complex variable $f(z)$, which has poles at a set of points $\{z_n\},\  n=1,2,3, ...$ with a limit point $z_0 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }z_n < \infty$. Then, $z_0$ must also be singular. My conjecture is that $z_0$ is a essential singularity.

One illustration of this is the function $f(z) = \frac 1 {e^{1/z}-1}$, which has simple poles at $z=\frac 1 {2\pi i n}$ ($n\in Z$) with residues $4\pi^2 n^2.$ This function has a essential singularity at $z=0$.

Do you think this is correct? If yes, is there any theorem regarding this?

Comment: There is an interesting exercise regarding this question in Churchill & Brown p.247 (exercise 69-11). It states as follows:

Let R denote the region consisting of all points inside and on a simple closed contour C. Use the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem and the fact that poles are isolated singular points to show that if f is analytic in the region R except for poles interior to C, then those poles must be finite in number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not correct. The concept of essential singularity is defined only for isolated singularities (as are the concepts of removable singularity and of pole). So, if a singularity is not isolated, it makes no sense to ask which type of singularity it is: removable, pole or essential.

In particular, it is not true that $0$ is an essential singularity of the function from your example.

Comment: I see. I was thinking about this while studying Mittag-Leffler theorem. A version of it states that if $f$ is meromorphic in $C$ with poles at points $z_n$ and residues $r_n$, and if $|f(z)/z| \rightarrow 0$ as $z \rightarrow \infty$, then $f$ can be written as 
$f(z) = f(0) + \sum_n (\frac {r_n}{z-z_n} +\frac {r_n}{z_n}).$

Is there similar result if we include non-isolated singular points (such as limit point of isolated poles) as in above example?